# Bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:inDirectory:

Tags: objective-c, ios, resources, path

In my application I have a lot of pictures divided into few categories (the following is an application tree inside a project and at my HDD):

```
ApplicationName
- Resources
-- Thumbs
-- Images
-- Buttons
-- Default.png
```

In the thumbs folder I have a lot of .png files. The problem is I want to know how many of these files are in this folder. I type such a command:

```
NSArray *namesArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@".png" inDirectory:@"Resources/Thumbs"];
```

And it doesn't find any files inside bundle. When I use inDirectory:@"." I get a list of all .png files (so from Images,Buttons + Default), while I need only this one catalog.

I've tried to add these folders to project by two ways: 1-"Create groups for any added folder" and 2-"Create folder references for any added folders".

When I use option 1, `inDirectory:@"Resources/Thumbs"];`, it doesn't work (namesArray is 0 objects). To test, I tried inDirectory:@"."], and it went out that path is:

```
 /Users/name.surname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/applicationNumber/applicationName.app/0.png
```

When I use option 2 while compiling I stop at "Attaching to applicationName..." and the project never runs.

How do I know how many images I have in my Thumbs folder...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use command:

```
NSArray *namesArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@".png" inDirectory:@"Thumbs/."];
```

And add folders as a reference, everything worked then ^^.

Comment: What do you mean "Add the folder as a reference"?

Comment: @Gal This question and answer is 2 years old. Please use xcassets.

Comment: you are right, but for the sake of developers that want to use the `pathsForResourcesOfType` I added an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

`NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@".png" inDirectory:@"Thumbs"];`

To use this function, you need to declare your folder like this (When you drag the folder into your bundle):

[image]