# Scanning the contents of a directory which is stored in an Xcode project in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, file

This seems to be a problem which is very difficult to explain. I am trying to read data from a folder full of files and the way I am trying to do this is by scanning the whole directory for all of the files. The file in question is stored in my Xcode project in the same directory as the view controllers and storyboards. Like so:

[image: thing]

I would like to be able to scan the contents of the "data" folder. Consider the following code:

```
var tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory()
var error: NSError?

let filesInDirectory: [String]! = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(tmpDir, error: &error) as? [String]
```

This scans the contents of the app's local folder and returns it as an array of the file names. I would like to be able to do this with the "data" folder in my Xcode project. The following code will find the contents of a single file which is stored in the same directory as the "data" folder.

```
let files = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sampleFile", ofType: "csv")
var contents = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
```

Is there a way in which I can combine the capabilities of the two in order to scan the contents of the "data" folder in the Xcode project and then return the file names as an array?

Answer (score 0):

Add the data folder to **Copy Bundle Resources** in **Build Phases** of your target.

Then you'll be able to read the path as it's within the same sandbox scope. (Assuming you are applying sandbox.) If not, just use absolute path/URL and you can access it directly without the copying process.

You might want to have a look here: [Cocoa contents of directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157997/cocoa-contents-of-directory)